# MacOS HighSierra File sharing with MX Linux

Tags: finder, network

Trying to set up file sharing between MacOS High Sierra and MX Linux. I am new to this and have never successfully networked two computers.

Using freshly installed versions of both OS's and a fresh ethernet-7 cable, I've tried creating connections from either computer to the other.

ON MACOS
When I click on the "Go" dropdown folder in MacOS and choose "Network", I get a network directory that SOMETIMES shows the Linux connection as "?MX" (that is, MX preceded by a greyed out question mark).

In the Network menu within System Preferences, it says

```
Status: Connected.
```

And other info about IP address and subnet mask, using DHCP

ON LINUX
On Linux, I see the Mac appear SOMETIMES in network directory.
But the file I place in the network folder doesn't appear on the Mac.
If I click on the iMac folder in Linux, I get these error messages.

```
Failed to open "eric's iMac".
Failed to receive share list from server. Connection timed out.
```

The iMac folder in Linux is SOMETIMES called dnssd-domain-eric%E2%80%20iMac._smb._tcp
which says 0 bytes unknown.
There's also a Windows network appearing SOMETIMES in the network directory, though no such network exists, to my knowledge.

Been working on this forever, tried everything I can think of.
Any suggestions much appreciated !!